# Building Silverlight 5 project without installing SDK

Tags: silverlight, msbuild

I'm a developer without access to the build server.  I am attempting to configure my silverlight project to build on the build server, without installed the Silverlight 5.0 SDK.  I can place all of the SDK files into a source folder, so I just need to redirect MSBuild to find them.

I've attempted to do this by editting the FrameworkRegistryBase tag in Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets file, but am still getting the same error message:

"The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed".

Can you tell me where the path to the SDK can be overridden?

Thanks